# Visual Studio - End debugger only when all forms have been closed

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm working in Visual Studio 2013 Premium on a Windows forms project. When I'm debugging my windows forms project and I close my start up form, all other forms stop too. I googled this problem and saw that in project --> properties there is a drop down list where you're able to change shutdown mode, which would solve my problem.

The shutdown mode option however is not present at my application properties. I can't find it anywhere else and searching the web didn't resolve this problem for me either, so what could it be?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want your application to close only when the user has manually closed *all* open forms? To me, that sounds like an application setting, not an IDE (i.e. Visual Studio) setting..

Comment: The setting he talks about is a project (application) setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That only applies to Visual Basic projects.

Here's your options:

- For Visual Basic projects, twiddle the option you found on Google
- For C# WPF projects, you can set the [Application.ShutdownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property
- For C# WinForms projects, you must either:

  - Accept that it will close when the main form closes
  - Prevent the main form from closing until all other forms have closed

Answer (score 3):

The [**Application.OpenForms Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be helpful to you:

### Definition:

> Gets a collection of open forms owned by the application.

### Example:

In the closing event of the main application you can put following code that will check if there's more than 1 form opened.

```
var openForms = Application.OpenForms;

if(openForms.Count > 1)
{
    //More than 1 form is opened: cancel the close-event
}
else
{
}
```